# Getting value of dropdown list in react

Tags: reactjs

In my react website I want to get value of dropdown list and store selected value i.e if user selects Admin value=1 is stored in database. How can I do this?

```
   <div className="col-lg-12">
    <select className="form-control" name="roleId" value={this.state.roleId} onChange={this.handleChange} id="sel" style={{ marginTop: "35px" }} required>
     <option> Role</option>
     <option value="1">Admin</option>
     <option value="2">Teacher</option>
     <option value="3">TeamLead</option>
    </select>
   </div>
```

Following are my functions

```
    handleChange = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }, () => this.validateName())
}
    handleSubmit(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { password, confirmPassword, name } = this.state
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            alert('passwords do not match')

        }
        else {
            axios.post('https://localhost:44310/api/Users/', this.state)
                .then((response: any) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('User has been added successfully')
                })
                .catch(function (error: any) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert('Sorry! Your request can not be processed at the moment')
                });
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange = (event: any) => {
this.setState({ roleId: event.target.value }, () => this.validateName()) }
```

I am assuming you would need the name of the drop to be `roleId` irrespective of the option user selects.

After this change, you would have the selected role in `this.state.roleId`

Comment: i want to get value of the option selected. For Example if user selects Admin value 1 is stored in roleId and if user selects Teacher value 2 is stored in roleId. I don't want to store admin or Teacher I want to store value.

Comment: `this.state.roleId` would have `1` if admin is selected.